# Casting API class to Inherited class

Tags: java, inheritance

Why will the following not work?  Is it not possible to cast like this?

I get the error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to MyMusicFile`

```
public class MyMusicFile extends java.io.File
{
  public MyMusicFile(String pathname) 
  {
    super(pathname);
  }

  public String artist;
  public String album;
  public String track;
  public String year;   
}

main(String[] args)
{
  File file = new File("/home/1.txt");
  MyMusicFile mmf = (MyMusicFile) file;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If `MyMusicFile` extends `File`, then `MyMusicFile` is also a `File`, but that doesn't make `File` a `MyMusicFile`. If you list all the super classes for each class, you'd get:

- File: java.lang.Object
- MyMusicFile: java.io.File, java.lang.Object

And you can assign any type to it's type or any other super type (say `Object` to `File`, or File to `MyMusicFile`).

You can think of it like this: `MyMusicFile` has all the fields and methods like `File`, plus some extra ones. So it's safe to assign an instance of `MyMusicFile` to a `File` because it will work (has all the required stuff), but a `File` doesn't have all the stuff `MyMusicFile` has (that extra stuff is missing), so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. What would you get if you try to cast a Horse to a Car? You may only cast something to something it actually is. For example, the following is OK:

```
 Object o = new Integer(345);
 Integer i = (Integer) o;
 Number n = (Number) o;
```

Because the object that the `o` variable references is an Integer, which is also a Number, which is also an Object.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are entirely correct, but also I should point out that some classes in Java are not designed for subclassing for most user needs, and `java.io.File` is one of these. You just create a File object that refers to your desired file. The point of subclassing is to add extra behavior to the original class, and that's not generally not necessary for a File.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, your code does not work because while MyMusicFile is a File, the inverse is not true (File is not a MyMusicFile). You should change your design from extension (is-a) to aggregation (has-a). Something like this:

```
public class MyMusicFileReader {
    private File musicFile;

    public MyMusicFileReader(File file) {
        super();
        musicFile = file;
    }

    public void load() {
        // load your info here
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("/home/1.txt");
    MyMusicFileReader mReader = new MyMusicFileReader(file);
    mReader.load();
}
```